# What does "will something to do but don't want" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/ZrZ-zX4zpsY). It is at around 3 minute and 20 second. Here it goes:

> But if I were to watch something someone **was willing to do but didn't want**, even if there is the slightest doubt that the sex acts or the scene wasn't pleasurable, this would turn me off.

I am confused because I cannot see the difference between *will* and *want*. How can someone will something to do, but don't want to do?

Comment: "Willing to" means that they are agreeing to what ever it is. That means, they are not doing it against their will. "Want" indicates desire. I may be *willing to* scrub the toilet, for example, because I know it needs to be done, but I do not *want* to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is "willing", not "will". A person who is merely willing consents to engage in some activity, likely to please someone else and perhaps even reluctantly. A person who "wants to do" something will do it to please himself. Examples:

> I am willing to drive you to the store.

This is an offer to provide a needed service.

> I want to drive you to the store.

This implies that the speaker will derive pleasure from providing the service, perhaps because he wants to spend time in the other's company.

Answer (score 0):

There **willing** means "not coerced".

They might have agreed to do certain things for money  but they would prefer not to do those things.